# Getting responseText error values out of JQuery error?

Tags: jquery, api, error-handling, responsetext

In my ajax .error function I'm trying to get out the values from the responseText being sent back from the API I'm getting for example

```
{"error":"Wrong Crendtials","error_description":"Provided username and password is incorrect"}
```

In my JavaScript its recognising there's errors, but I can't get it to get into the individual items which I want to get to show messages based on the error response?

```
).error(function (xhr, status, err) {
        var errorData = xhr.responseText;
        if (errorData != null) {
            alert("has errors");
           alert("error - " + errorData.error + " - desc " + errorData.error_description);
        }
    });
```

I'm sure this is something really basic, but I'm struggling to find an answer that breaks the values down for me?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have json array in your response its just json object . So to access it simply write `errorData.error` , `errorData.error_description` .

Comment: I just get 'undefined' however when doing that?

Comment: when you console do you see right value for `errorData` ?  Also you don't need `each` loop here simply print like above

Comment: Yes, so if I will get this - "{"error":"Wrong Crendtials","error_description":"Provided username and password is incorrect"}" - as shown in my question. If I debug in VS its showing the data within errorData but as soon as you hover over the values its undefined?

Comment: Hi check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/ubcpgv4o/) to understand better.

Comment: Thanks, I get the fiddle. If I copy that into my application it works as it should and weirdly that's what is showing as the JSON in my fiddle back when I run with the responseText. But it just doesnt find the values when you call them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221225/discussion-between-swati-and-slowlygettingthere).

Answer (score 0):

With many thanks to Swati. This was resolved with:

```
var jsonResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
alert("Error: " + jsonResponse.error + " Description: " + jsonResponse.error_description);
```